# ArrayList to ListViewDataItem[]

Tags: c#, collections

I want to `convert` or cast an `ArrayList` to `ListViewDataItem[]`

Any suggestions ? prefereably the simplest way.

Comment: What have you done? ArrayList of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListViewDataItem[] elements =  (ListViewDataItem[]) yourArrayList.ToArray(typeof (ListViewDataItem));
```

Comment: Thanks, +1, I'll go testing it